# How to exit from editing part in place?

Tags: solidworks

I was editing assembly, then selected one part and presses "Edit part in place".

How to get out of this mode back to assembly editing?

Comment: You should just be able to click the "Edit Component" button to de-select it and go back to assembly editing mode.

Comment: Please include a screenshot of the situation our software is stuck in, then it will be easy to explain how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Deselect this option and it will return to the assembly.

[image]